# Error en Función que cambia background de una tabla a partir de un array[JAVASCRIPT / HTML]

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy escribiendo una función que a partir de un array de colores (ej.: ["1e81b0","eeeee4","e28743"]) cambia el background-color de las celdas de una tabla.

Es la primera vez que intento pasar un valor de un input a una variable y creo que no lo estoy haciendo bien. No sé dónde está el error. A ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

Os escribo la explicación / código a continuación.

Esta es la tabla (cada celda tiene su ID):

```
<table class='sudoku'>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="one"></td>
        <td id="two"></td>
        <td id="three"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="four"></td>
        <td id="five"></td>
        <td id="six"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="seven"></td>
        <td id="eight"></td>
        <td id="nine"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hay una primera función que toma cada elemento del array, le añade un "#" delante (#1e81b0) y le cambia el background color a cada una de las celdas:

```
function Mycolor(arrayOfColors) {
        var element1 = document.getElementById("one");
        element1.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[0];
        var element2 = document.getElementById("two");
        element2.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[1];
        var element3 = document.getElementById("three");
        element3.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[2];
        var element4 = document.getElementById("four");
        element4.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[3];
        var element5 = document.getElementById("five");
        element5.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[4];
        var element6 = document.getElementById("six");
        element6.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[5];
        var element7 = document.getElementById("seven");
        element7.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[6];
        var element8 = document.getElementById("eight");
        element8.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[7];
        var element9 = document.getElementById("nine");
        element9.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[8];}
```

Ahora hay una segunda función que coge el texto de un input text y lo transforma en un array. Después ejecuta la función Mycolor dándole el array como argumento:

```
function pasarArray(){
    var text = document.getElementById('texto').value;
    console.log(text);
    var colores = text.split(',');
    console.log(colores);
    Mycolor(colores);
}
```

Este es el input text:

```
<form name="formulario" action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="prod" id="texto" placeholder="Escribe un array"><br>
    <input type="button" name="enviar" value="enviar" onclick="pasarArray()">
</form>
```

No sé dónde se encuentra el error, pero al darle al botón de enviar, no ocurre nada.

Comment: A mi me funciona perfectamente. Tan sol un detalle, pon algo de contenido en las celdas pues al no tener nada dentro es probable que no veas los colores, pues no tienen longitud (a menos que tengas un CSS que les fuerce un width)

Answer (score 1):

Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda. Tengo en cuenta vuestros inputs.

Además, encontré el fallo principal: Estaba introduciendo en el input *["1e81b0","eeeee4","e28743"]*  cuando debía introducir *1e81b0, eeeee4, e28743*.

Esta ha sido mi primera experiencia preguntando en Stack overflow y estoy muy contento con la comunidad. Espero tener el nivel para aportar yo también en el futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Si no muestra contenido la celda no podras ver el cambio de colores

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tabla</title>
    <style>
thead,
tfoot {
    background-color: #3f87a6;
    color: #fff;
}

tbody {
    background-color: #e4f0f5;
}

caption {
    padding: 10px;
    caption-side: bottom;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: .8rem;
}

td,
th {
    border: 1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190);
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

</style>
    <script>
    function pasarArray(){
    var text = document.getElementById('texto').value;
  
    var colores = text.split(',');
   // console.log(colores);
    Mycolor(colores);
}
        function Mycolor(arrayOfColors) {
        var element1 = document.getElementById("one");
        element1.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[0];
        var element2 = document.getElementById("two");
        element2.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[1];
        var element3 = document.getElementById("three");
        element3.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[2];
        var element4 = document.getElementById("four");
        element4.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[3];
        var element5 = document.getElementById("five");
        element5.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[4];
        var element6 = document.getElementById("six");
        element6.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[5];
        var element7 = document.getElementById("seven");
        element7.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[6];
        var element8 = document.getElementById("eight");
        element8.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[7];
        var element9 = document.getElementById("nine");
        element9.style.backgroundColor= '#' + arrayOfColors[8];
        }
        
        
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h31> Para ver cambios en color celda ingresa por ejp :1e81b0,eeeee4,e28743</h3>
<form name="formulario" action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="prod" id="texto" placeholder="Escribe un array"><br>
    <input type="button" name="enviar" value="enviar" onclick="pasarArray()">
</form>

<table class='table'>
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Primera</th>
      <th>Segunda</th>
      <th>Tercera</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="one">1</td>
        <td id="two">2</td>
        <td id="three">3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="four">4</td>
        <td id="five">5</td>
        <td id="six">6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="seven">7</td>
        <td id="eight">8</td>
        <td id="nine">9</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>


</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```